# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, types, int, typeerror

In Python 2.7:

```
a=80
b=100

def status(hp, maxhp):
    print "You are at %r percent health." % hp*100/maxhp

status(a,b)
```

Returns:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

I've already tried putting int() around each variable and each combination of variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%` operator has higher precedence than `*` or `/`.

What you meant is:

```
"You are at %r percent health." % (hp * 100 / maxhp)
```

What you got is:

```
("You are at %r percent health." % hp) * 100 / maxhp
```

Edit: actually, I'm wrong. They have the same precedence and thus are applied left to right.

[Docs: operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Thanks, I was never taught that modulus was considered an operand in this case, or where it stood in the order of operations. I ended up fixing it by making another variable and feeding that into the string.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap parens around the expression, so it is fully evaluated before trying to have the result substituted into the string.

something like:

```
print "my string with this '%d' value" % (hp * 100 / maxhp)
```