# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, quicksort

I have written the code for quick sort in python, but this code is throwing an error.

```
----------


    k=0
    def partition(arr,low_index,high_index):
        key = arr[low_index]
        i = low_index + 1;
        j = high_index

        while True:
            while (i<high_index and key>=arr[i]):
                i+=1
            while (key<arr[j]):
                j-=1
            if i<j:
                arr[i,j] = arr[j,i]
            else:
                arr[low_index,j]=arr[j,low_index]
                return j

    def quicksort(arr,low_index,high_index):
         if low_index < high_index:
            j = partition(low_index,high_index,arr)
            print("Pivot element with index "+str(j)+" has thread "+str(k))
            if left<j:
                k=k+1
                quicksort(arr,low_index, j - 1)
            if i<right:
                k=k+1
                quicksort(arr,j+1,high_index)
         return arr

    n = input("Enter the value n ")
    arr=input("Enter the "+str(n)+" no. of elements ")
    brr=quicksort(arr,0,n-1)
    print("Elements after sorting are "+str(brr))

----------
```

The error it is throwing is

> Enter the value n 4
>
> > Enter the 4 no. of elements [5,6,2,7]
> >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> >         File "C:\Users\devendrabhat\Documents\dev\dev\quick.py", line 38, in 
> >             brr=quicksort(arr,0,n-1)
> >         TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371555/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: can u explain please

Comment: Python receives input as a string. You need to use the function int() on that input to turn it into an integer and catch possible exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n is string. So you need to change it to int:

```
n = int(n)
```

If you input [5,6,2,7] on line 37, python interpret it as string like "[5,6,2,7]".
So, you need to convert string to list.

```
arr = eval(arr)
```

Comment: Use try and except ValueError, without it's not a complete solution.

Comment: If you give a string to eval function, the string is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.
So, if you give a list as string like “[5,6,2,7]”, it is parsed and evaluated. As a result, you can get list object like [5,6,2,7].

If you want to know eval in detail, please look at following site.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Calling `eval()` directly on the unfiltered value from `input()` is one of the worst ideas ever. At least use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change n to an integer, not a string.  Your error is telling you, that you are trying to perform an operation (- in this case) on a string and an integer. Change `str(n)` to `int(n)` so you have the same type throughout.

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring 'n' as string there in your code. And trying to perform arithmetic operation with string.

So it is giving that error. Change this `str(n)` to `int(n)`.

It will work !!!